# Buscar Locais por categoria

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estou utilizando a api google places que retorna um JSON, consegui buscar locais por `lat` e `long` e também pelo `placeid`, agora preciso buscar o local pelo `tipo/categoria` por exemplo: restaurante, academia, eletrônicos e etc.

Para buscar por `lat`/`long` usei esse URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location="+String.valueOf(lat)+","+String.valueOf(longt)+"&radius=100&sensor=true&key="+APKEY);
```

Mas não to conseguindo buscar por `categoria`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscas no [Google Places WS API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search?hl=pt-br) por uma categoria, como você disse, você deve informar como parâmetro, além dos obrigatórios (`location`, `radius`, `key` e `radius`), o atributo `types`, conforme documentação:

> `types` — restringe os resultados a locais que correspondam a pelo menos um dos tipos especificados.

Um exemplo buscando por academias seria neste formato:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-27.6142358,-48.4828248&radius=1000&types=gym&key=<api_key>
```

Caso precise buscar mais de um tipo, como por exemplo academias e bares, basta separar os tipos com um `|`, então ficaria assim:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-27.6142358,-48.4828248&radius=1000&types=gym|bar&key=<api_key>
```

Para todos os tipos de locais, você pode verificar neste link: [Tipos de locais](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=pt-br)

Comment: opa maravilha era o que eu estava procurando, vlw